# How to avoid slow equals for interned objects?

Tags: java, guava, equality, string-interning

I'm creating a few rather big objects and many of them are duplicates. So I thought about using Guava's `Interner` for them and always work with the interned object only (i.e., each object gets interned just after creation).

It occurred to me that `equals` of those objects is rather slow (and gets used a lot) and that I actually never need it, as `a.equals(b)` is equivalent to `a == b` after interning. Unfortunately, the `Interner` itself uses `equals` so I have to override it for the single use.

I wonder if there's a simple way to have my equals and eat it?

---

*Disclaimer: I know about the [root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and I'm not sure if optimization on this place is worth the effort. However, I'm interested if the above problem has a nice solution.*

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use pattern as to where you want to take the performance hit.

If you're going to be doing a lot of comparisons *after* creating an object and you know you have a high occurrence of duplicates, then the flyweight pattern may make sense as all your post-creation comparisons can be done via reference equality.

The other thing to consider is space efficiency; you mention they're large objects. What's more important? If you're saving a ton of memory by pooling objects, that may be a win.

Profiling your code trying both approaches can also help you make that decision.

**Edit to add:** That said I'm surprised their interner is relying solely on `equals()`. In my head it would make much more sense to rely on `hashcode()` and only use `equals()` for collisions.

Comment: I didn't mean the `Interner` relies *solely* on equals, it's a sort of hash map (actually the `MapMaker`'s map). But it's the *sole* reason I need `equals`. I'd prefer not to override equals because of its uses in other maps.

Comment: Right, that's a sane way to do it. That means the only time `equals()` is being called is on a hash collision, which means rarely given a decent `hashcode()` method (depending on the number of buckets). And if you're overriding `hashcode()` ... you need to be overriding `equals()` ... for the same purpose in other maps (::confused::)

Answer (score 1):

If your equals method uses "a == b" internally, is that fast enough?

```
class BigObject {
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == this) return true;
    if(o == null) return false;
    // a bunch of other stuff
  }
}
```

As a further step, you might consider wrapping "a bunch of other stuff" in a (private) method, which would encourage equals to be inlined.  Hard to know when that stuff works, but ...

Comment: I don't think inlining `equals` will work in the relevant places (`HashMap#get` etc.) as there are other maps in the program and `equals` is heavily overloaded.